# Codeigniter prevent user from going to previous page

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

Is there any way to prevent my users from hitting the back button to go to a previous page? I am afraid that if they perform a payment on the payment page, and they hit back, they will be brought to the details page where they have to submit the form again which will cause a double entry into the database. Currently I have tried this method.

1. Generate a timestamp from a form in a hidden input
2. Put the timestamp into a session
3. Compare if the timestamp is similar when I submit the form. Only submit the form if it isn't
4. redirect($this->agent->referrer()); if the timestamps are similar

I found this method from another answer but so far it doesn't work. Won't the timestamps definitely not be similar?

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery to prevent user from back button. 
Add following code to script.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
              return "Leaving the page will result reset of all unsaved changes.";
}
```

Comment: Sorry where do I place this?

Comment: You can add this in script tag at bottom of the page <script> //code </script>

Comment: Sorry but is there a way to prevent them from going at all? It seems like if they choose to go back, they can still submit the form again

Answer (score 0):

Usually when user hit payment button, the website will lead user to a new page and let user complete payment on that new page. For the previous old page you need lock it and popup a window to inform user like:

[image]

I take this screenshot from the payment process of Skype, and I think if you are confused about the question that you described, you better to see some big e-commerce corporations' (like Amazon, ebay) solution and imitate it.